# Layered navigation $_filter->getHtml() returns empty string

Tags: magento-1.8, layered-navigation, ce-1.8.1.0, filtered-nav

I have the attributes correctly configured to be displayed for layered navigation. The attribute names are showing but the "attribute values" are not. `$_filter->getHtml()` simply returns empty strings (see pic).

I have an multi store and on my other stores the layered navigation is showing just fine. Magento 1.8.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you enable Template Path Hints AND Add Block Names to Hints in the developer menu in the magento configuration.

This can be seen if you select the website (not the default configuration) as your scope.

This will allow you to see, on the front end what block is being referenced, and possibly what is overwriting what you are expecting (e.g. magento's default functionality).

I experienced the same issue recently, and it turned out that the theme was being overwritten by a badly written plugin, this maybe the same for you.